# JavaScript strange behavior when set a class by setAttribute

Tags: javascript, css

I want to set a specific class on some of the lines of my html code by JS. 
On the output I have four lines and lines 1 and 2 and 4 (which started with Arabic characters) should be affected and get a red background. But it's strange why isn't second line affected by the class. Is there something wrong I did?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>This is</title>
<style> .rtl {background: red;}</style>
</head>


<body>

<div class="chat-item__text">سلام</div>

<div class="chat-item__text">بله</div>

<div class="chat-item__text">koo</div>

<div class="chat-item__text">اینور</div>

<script>


function checkRtl( character )
{
    var RTL = ['ا','ب','پ','ت','س','ج','چ','ح','خ','د','ذ','ر','ز','ژ','س','ش','ص','ض','ط','ظ','ع','غ','ف','ق','ک','گ','ل','م','ن','و','ه','ی'];
    if( RTL.indexOf( character ) > -1)
    {
          return true;
    } else
    {
          return false;
    }

}

function init()
{
      var chatText = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-item__text");
      for (var i = 0; i < chatText.length; i++)
      {
            var eachLine = chatText[i].innerHTML;
            var firstChar = eachLine.charAt(0);
            console.log(firstChar);
            if (checkRtl(firstChar))
            {
                  chatText[i].setAttribute("class", "rtl");
            }

      }
}
window.onload = init;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Element.classList.add()`  instead of `setAttribute()`.

That error has occurred :

That you used `setAttribute` is setting class as a new Attribute.

```js
function checkRtl(character) {
  var RTL = ['ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ت', 'س', 'ج', 'چ', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'ژ', 'س', 'ش', 'ص', 'ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ک', 'گ', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'و', 'ه', 'ی'];
  if (RTL.indexOf(character) > -1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}

function init() {
  var chatText = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-item__text");
  for (var i = 0; i < chatText.length; i++) {
    var eachLine = chatText[i].innerHTML;
    var firstChar = eachLine.charAt(0);
    console.log(firstChar);
    if (checkRtl(firstChar)) {
      chatText[i].classList.add('rtl');
      //chatText[i].setAttribute("class", "rtl");
    }

  }
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>This is</title>
  <style>
    .rtl {
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>

  <div class="chat-item__text">سلام</div>

  <div class="chat-item__text">بله</div>

  <div class="chat-item__text">koo</div>

  <div class="chat-item__text">اینور</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there a simple explanation why this works and that doesn't? A link to an explanation is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> [**`Document.getElementsByClassName()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)  live `HTMLCollection`. The term **Live** could be explained as `dynamic` which is updated when `DOM` is updated.

So in your case, if you debug, `for-loop` is being iterated for only `3` times as `setAttribute` will replace the `class` of the element and hence `length` of the `Collection` will get affected(reduced).

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to select elements which returns `NodeList` and is not **live**

```js
function checkRtl(character) {
  var RTL = ['ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ت', 'س', 'ج', 'چ', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'ژ', 'س', 'ش', 'ص', 'ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ک', 'گ', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'و', 'ه', 'ی'];
  return RTL.indexOf(character) > -1; //Could be simplified like this
}

function init() {
  var chatText = document.querySelectorAll(".chat-item__text");
  for (var i = 0; i < chatText.length; i++) {
    var eachLine = chatText[i].innerHTML;
    var firstChar = eachLine.charAt(0);
    console.log(checkRtl(firstChar))
    if (checkRtl(firstChar)) {
      chatText[i].setAttribute("class", "rtl");
    }
  }
}
window.onload = init;
```

```css
.rtl {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-item__text">سلام</div>
<div class="chat-item__text">بله</div>
<div class="chat-item__text">koo</div>
<div class="chat-item__text">اینور</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/z1gm0aac/)

**Note:** If you want to have multiple classes, go with the `Element.classList.add()`  instead of `setAttribute()`

Comment: Thank you so much. Your elaborate answer helps me a lot. Thanks.